# Error trying to write data on google's fit web aplication via rest api

Tags: rest, api, google-fit

I'm trying to write data on google's fit via rest api. The idea is to write data on google's rest api, and the goal is to show that information on both google fit's web and app.

The information that i'm trying to write is a session (equals to workout)

Request:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions/11xxxx

Body:

`{
  "id": "11xxxx",
  "name": "My example workout",
  "description": "A very intense workout",
  "startTimeMillis": 1396710000000,
  "endTimeMillis": 1396713600000,
  "version": 1,
  "lastModifiedToken": "exampleToken",
  "application": {
    "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.fitness", 
    "version": "web"
  },
  "activityType": 1
}`

Response:

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Application package name (com.google.android.apps.fitness) provided by un-trusted source.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Application package name (com.google.android.apps.fitness) provided by un-trusted source.", 
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: I think you need to get [authorization token](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization) to be able for your application to request on Fitness APi everytime it send data. Additionally, to guide you on process you can check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions).

Comment: I'm making the calls with authorization token, the problem is: I can't write my own data on google fit application (both phone and web). But I can write my own sessions.